# Recharts - change height based on chart data in vertical bar chart

Tags: reactjs, bar-chart, responsive, web-frontend, recharts

I am using dynamic data as the data props for recharts bar chart.
I set the min height of wrapper component of chart component, but the chart height is just like the min height that I set. So when the length of props data is long, then chart looks ugly though I set the barSize, barGap, and etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by wrapping `ResponsiveContainer` and set the height of the container as variable according to the length of data props.

```
<ResponsiveContainer height={props.data.length * (props.barSize + props.barGap)}>
   {chart component}
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

Comment: Please reference this link to learn more details about `ResponsiveContainer`
https://recharts.org/en-US/api/ResponsiveContainer